# Testing SQLite using Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-sqlite, robolectric

I have a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper and carries out database functions. I want to write a test for it using Robolectric. I am confident that robolectric is set up fine because I have a ton of other tests that work. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. I copied the database from my device to the test/res/ folder.

   String filePath = getClass().getResource("/UserData.db").toURI().getPath();
       SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
               (new File(filePath)).getAbsolutePath(),
               null,
               SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

This gave me a nullpointerexception. It appears that getResource() is always returning null.

2. Next, I tried directly calling the method that adds records to the database

   User user = new User("username", "friendlyName", "password", "vin");
   userDao.addUser(user);

This also throws an NPE where the database is first accessed.

I can't figure out how to fix the null pointers, and the only other option I can think of it to write a custom Shadow class. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please also add full stracktraces of the exceptions you are encountering

Comment: Turns out it was an issue in my code. It's a good thing I have unit tests :P Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use in your tests

```
DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(Robolectric.application);
```

where DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper and its constructor look like

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```